# PHP Erlang Bridge # ei_connect error

Tags: erlang

I installed the **mypeb** php apache erlang and more.

mypeb is here : http://code.google.com/p/mypeb/

I need to connect Erlang node and call it.

then my php code is :

```
$link = peb_connect('db@www.zangyu.org',  'abc');
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . peb_error());
}
```

`db@www.zangyu.org` is my Erlang node,

I noticed the following connection error: ei_connect error

help so ,thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using ProtocolBuffers or ASN.1 to communicate between PHP and Erlang instead of this bridge.